# To Search data in a given range in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have data like this:

```
ABC DEF 123 456 STU 567-89 XYZ 234  
123 345 789 ERT FGHT TYUI FGHT 456  
HHKHFS NOR TEST TEST1 5678 NOT TEST
```

Trying to format it as below output in which I can use to cut the string from any range (from 1st-3rd,2nd-4th,1st-5th) etc. and I should paste the cut part in a new page. Lets say I decided to copy 1-3 range then the output should be like:

```
ABC DEF 123  
123 345 789  
HHKHFS NOR TEST
```

Data can be comma (,) or space separated

Basically what I am looking for is suppose I need to cut first three column values, I should be able to cut that and later if I want to cut next three value that also can be taken.

Comment: What's your question? :)  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your task using macro.

If you want to copy 1-3 range for your sample text, you can record the following macro ("Macro" > "Start Recording" in main menu):

`Ctrl-Right, Ctrl-Right, Ctrl-Right, Shift-End, Backspace, Backspace, Down, Home`.

Then you can repeat this macro multiple times to handle each line.

To handle text delimited by both spaces and commas using this method, you can preprocess your text by replacing commas with spaces.